# Creating an array of associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, performance

I am fetching rows from the DB and returning the result in JSON. The output needs to be an array of associative arrays.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($resultSet as $r)
{
  $output[$i]['key1'] = $r['col1'];
  $output[$i]['key2'] = $r['col2'];
  ...
  $output[$i]['keyN'] = $r['colN'];
  $i++;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Is there anything wrong with this approach? If yes, what is it?

Comment: Which DB API are you using?  If PDO, your best bet will be to alias the columns to whatever you want their names to be (`SELECT a as b` or `SELECT a b`) and then use `fetchAll()`.  Not sure what other APIs have a method like that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring `$i=0;` before the loop, you can also write :

```
foreach($resultSet as $i => $r)
{
  $output[$i]['key1'] = $r['col1'];
  $output[$i]['key2'] = $r['col2'];
  ...
  $output[$i]['keyN'] = $r['colN'];
}
```

Also, if you could rename your column in the DB query, you could have :

```
foreach($resultSet as $i => $r)
{
  $output[$i] = $r;
}
```

Which is pretty much like doing `$output = $resultSet;`

**Edit :**
If you do need to do some processing on `$resultSet` for whatever reason and you'd rather have different names, you can consider doing :

```
for (array('key1' => 'col1', ... 'keyN' => 'colN' as key => col)
{
   $output[$i][$key] = $r[$col];
}
```

Comment: The $i IS outside the loop in my actual code. I have updated the question. The reason I am not using the resultset directly is that I do some operation on the resultset array before output. But I think, I might as well think about modifying my query and do all the operatrions in the SQL itself, so that I could simply return the resultset. Isn't it ?

Comment: Oops I messed up when I copy-pasted in my editor. You can consider my first comment then.

Comment: I edited my post. Not sure if it would help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to map Columns from the resulting rows such that:

```
Row | Column 1 | Column 2
1   | Value 1  | Value 2
2   | Value 2  | Value 2
```

Results in:

```
$rows = array(
    1 => array(
        'Column 1' => 'Value 1',
        'Column 2' => 'Value 2'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'Column 1' => 'Value 1',
        'Column 2' => 'Value 2'
    ),
);
```

If your PDO returns the values in numerical position, you can do this:

```
$columns = array(
    'Column 1',
    'Column 2'
);

$rows = array_map(function($row) use ($columns) {
    return array_combine($columns, $row);
}, $resultSet);
```

Or, if the `$resultSet` is associative, and you want to keep the names:

```
$columns = array_flip(array(
    'Column 1',
    'Column 2'
));

$rows = array_map(function($row) use ($columns) {
    return array_intersect_key($row, $columns);
}, $resultSet);
```

OR, if your PDO returns them in an Associative array, but the Column names need to be change:

```
$columns = array(
    'Column 1' => 'Key 1',
    'Column 2' => 'Key 1'
);

$rows = array_map(function($row) use ($columns) {
    $return = array();
    foreach($columns as $from => $to) {
        $return[$to] = !empty($row[$from]) ? $row[$from] : NULL;
    }
    return $return;
}, $resultSet);
```

That last one would work for either situation, really, as it will take the value at `$row[$from]` and place it at `$result[$to]`, which would account for numerical indices or string indices.  Also, the `empty()` check will suppress PHP errors, and will ensure that you have a value at each position.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
$i = 0;
foreach($resultSet as $key => $value){
    $output[$i++][$key] = $value;
}
```

Given a `$resultSet` like this:

```
$resultSet['key0'] = 'value0';
$resultSet['key1'] = 'value1';
$resultSet['key2'] = 'value2';
$resultSet['key3'] = 'value3';
$resultSet['key4'] = 'value4';
$resultSet['key5'] = 'value5';
```

The above code will produce something as follows:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [key0] => value0 )
    [1] => Array ( [key1] => value1 )
    [2] => Array ( [key2] => value2 )
    [3] => Array ( [key3] => value3 )
    [4] => Array ( [key4] => value4 )
    [5] => Array ( [key5] => value5 )
)
```

Echoing `$output[0]['key0]` will output `value0` (or an array if value0 is an array).

As a side note, you could actually get completely rid of $i, and just do the following:

```
foreach($resultSet as $key => $value){
    $output[][$key] = $value;
}
```

Do let me know if I completely misunderstood the question at hand though :)